# MUI data grid transfer table with search bars on both sides

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Created transfer table with search boxes on both the sides with mock data.
Solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/transfer-table-with-search-bar-on-both-sides-sovijk

https://codesandbox.io/s/transfer-table-with-search-bar-on-both-sides-sovijk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.